# Android studio is not refreshing arguments for changed constructors in dart

Tags: android-studio, dart, validation, arguments

I'm an inexperienced dev so I hope my vocabulary is correct. I've been using my android studio for a year without issue but for the last 2 days, whenever I change the signature of a method/constructor (e.g. add/remove an argument), the calling program unit errors out that I supplied too many/too few arguments. It is asif android studio doesn't refresh the signatures of the methods and keep enforcing the old signature.
When I restart AS, then it suddenly knows the new signature. Is there a place somewhere in the settings where I may have disabled it?
Does the language and plugins matter? I'm using Dart and flutter.

Some versions:
Android studio on Win10: 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Dart: 213.7433
Flutter: 71.0.3

Some additional notes. When the caller and callee are in the same file, then it updates the validation correctly. However, when there are in separate dart files, it doesn't update.

Am I writing my import incorrectly?

```
import 'dropdowns/DeckDropdown.dart';
```

Here's my constructor:

```
DeckDropdown (this.selectedValue ,this.another, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

Calling side:

```
DeckDropdown instDeckDropdown = DeckDropdown("arg1","arg2");
```

Errors that I receive on arg2: "1 positional argument(s) expected, but 2 found. "

Answer (score 0):

Oh this is crazy. I just found the issue. The folder where I had the file is called "Dropdowns" not "dropdowns". So androidstudio/dart finds the file for some parts of its logic and but for knowing/updating the signature of methods etc it is case sensitive. When correcting the case on the import it works.